# how to use java scanner and regex for removing punctuation marks in input text, but not "i.e."

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

How do i read this sentence and parse it using scanner to get the below output?

Input: **"it is red i.e. RED. not read."**

Output: it is red i.e. RED not read

i tried the below but it doesnt remove the periods at the end of the words:

```
Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
lineReader.useDelimiter(("\\s+(\\W*\\s)?"));
```

edit: let me change this requirement: how do i remove all punctuation marks from the input text but not when its a period (.) between two letters like i.e.

Comment: the `.` is a reserved character, you have to escape it with `\\ ` if you literally want to match a `.` otherwise it matches any symbol.

Answer (score 1):

`"(?<!i\\.e)\\.? |\\.$"` should do the trick.

In English this regex says a delimiter is any of the following:

- a space
- a dot and a space (unless the dot is preceded by "i.e")
- a dot and the end of the string.

With regards to your edit, try `"((?<=\\s\\w{1,10})[^\\w\\s])?\\s|[^\\w\\s]$"`

`[^\\w\\s]` means any character that is not a letter or a digit or whitespace (i.e. punctuation).

`(?<=\\s\\w{1,10})[^\\w\\s])?\\s` means a space that may be preceded by punctuation if there is no other punctuation before the next previous space. That is, it will not match the `.[space]` in `e.g.[space]` because there is a full stop between the e and the g. The lookbehind (`(?<=\\s\\w{1,10})`) is required to have a maximum length, and so may not use the zero-or-more or one-or-more operators (`*` and `+`). I put an arbitary limit of 10 because I don't know of any words or abbreviations that contain punctuation and are more than a few characters.

edit: I tested the new regex on the `it is red i.e. RED. not read. e.g. 1,2, done!` and it produced:

- it
- is
- red
- i.e.
- RED
- not
- read
- e.g.
- 1,2,
- done

Comment: thanks, this does work! can you tell me how i can use this to remove any other punctuation marks as well (see edit)?

Comment: See my edit. Your additional requirement makes the regex a lot more complicated. It may be better to extend scanner and to override next so that it strips offending punctuation from the token.

Comment: yea your solution works but the 10 letter limit is messing it up. see input: it is red i.e. celebrations, i.e. RED. not read.

Comment: Just increase the limit to whatever you think is reasonable